# Does the School of Necromancy feature Command Undead have a usage limit?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, necromancy

Does the School of Necromancy feature Command Undead have a usage limit? The feature does not specify the number of times I can use it, all it says is

> As an **action**, you can choose one undead that you can see within 60 feet of you.

This feature does not seem to use spell slots or state the number of times I can use it in a day.
Does this mean I can use this skill at will? 
Or I can only use this in combat because it requires an action?

If none of these are correct please clarify.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It doesn't** have a usage limit, but **It does** have a control limit on the number of undead.

1. The answer to how many can you control at a time is in the complete feature description:

   > If it fails, it becomes friendly to you and obeys your commands **until you use this feature again**.

This effectively limits your **Command Undead** to **One** Undead type creature, letting you change your focus to another Undead if you so desire, but losing control over the first one in the process.

2. Regarding how many times you can use it in a day. reading the full description only mentions:

   > If it succeeds, you can’t use this feature on it again.

This means you can use it again on any other number of Undead creatures, provided you keep in mind the requirement to only have **One** under command at any one time.

**In general**, if a feature uses a spell slot or has any other distinct requirements they will be mentioned in the description as explicitly as possible.

Comment: seems fair and balanced. Thank you for answering :)